# Most pythonic way to find matching string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having code posted below how can I improve it's implementation? I am trying no to have to much if-logic in my code and I am pretty certain that there are much faster mechanisms in Python to deal with such tasks:

```
      is_sat = re.search('sat', destination, re.IGNORECASE) 
      if is_sat is not None:
            temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, self.sat_zone_dict)
            data_type = 'SAT' + str(temp_zone)
            self.log_handler.update(destination+" "+data_type+"\n")
        else:
            if destination.find("All") > 0:
                temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, self.mn_zone_dict)
                data_type = 'ALL_' + str(temp_zone)
                self.log_handler.update("ALL destination: "+destination + " " + data_type + "\n")
            elif destination.find("Mobile") > 0:
                temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, self.mn_zone_dict)
                data_type = 'MOB_'+str(temp_zone)
            elif destination.find("Fixed") > 0:
                temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, self.mn_zone_dict)
                data_type = 'FIX_'+str(temp_zone)
            elif destination.find("NGN") > 0:
                temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, self.sat_zone_dict)
                data_type = 'NGN_' + str(temp_zone)
```

*determine_zone()* method allows me to match with key: value dict, but while I first have to search for the pattern in the destination field it makes no sense to me to add another operation which would exactly extract position of the "All', 'Mobile' etc. in my string.

@EDIT
As @zwer asked here is *determine_zone()* implementation:

```
 def determine_zone(price: int, zone_dict: dict) -> int:

     zone = None

     try:
         for (key, value) in zone_dict.items():
             if price < value:
                 zone = key
                 return zone

         if zone is None:
             zone = zone_dict.__len__() + 1
             return zone

     except TypeError:
         raise TypeError
```

Comment: Is the `log_handler` or `determine_zone` an important part of the question?

Comment: Can you post the `determine_zone()` method, too?

Comment: I'd start from factoring out the common subexpressions `self.determine_zone(value, self.sat_zone_dict)` and `str(temp_zone)` into variables, making the code immediately less noisy.

Comment: Your code works? and you want it refactored for - less lines? prettier? ???

Comment: @wwii - of course it works. I want it to be faster. I know that this part of code is a bottleneck of my app and it makes it to work longer then I would want to.

Comment: @PeterWood log_handler is just a simple write-to-file function under the hood.

Comment: @zwer - please find determine_zone() in an edit

Comment: @9000 could you elaborate more on that matter?
I would say that factoring them into separate expression would make code more noisy. But maybe I don't get your idea. Could you give an example of implementation?

Comment: @wwii Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela - CV and comments removed.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out the common code. Wherever you see any copy-pasted code (and posted a snipped with a lot of it), it's a valid target for factoring out — not necessarily to a separate function, but in a way that prevents it from being repeated.

```
is_sat = ...
# temp_zone is calculated only once, and turned to string immediately.
temp_zone = str(self.determine_zone(value, self.sat_zone_dict))
if is_sat is None: 
   for prefix in ('ALL', 'MOB', 'FIX', 'NGN'):
     if prefix in destination:
       data_type = prefix + '_' + temp_zone  # Only once.
       if prefix == 'ALL':
         log("ALL destination: "+destination + " " + data_type + "\n") 
   # You _might_ have a case where none of the prefix values were found.
   # Think about handling it, or make sure it cannot happen. 
else:
  data_type = 'SAT_' + temp_zone
  self.log_handler.update(destination + " " + data_type + "\n")
```

This is basically it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your logic is exactly the same, only the `data_type` value differs (and in two instances what dict you pass to `self.determine_zone()`). You can create a small lookup dict and then just iterate through it until you find your candidates, e.g.:

```
# sadly, the first check doesn't appear to follow the same rules - i.e. it's case insensitive
# you'll have to do it manually, i.e.:
if "sat" in destination.lower():
    temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, self.sat_zone_dict)
    data_type = 'SAT' + str(temp_zone)
    self.log_handler.update(destination + " " + data_type+"\n")
else:
    lookup = {"All": ["ALL_", self.mn_zone_dict],
              "Mobile": ["MOB_", self.mn_zone_dict],
              "Fixed": ["FIX_", self.mn_zone_dict],
              "NGN": ["FIX_", self.sat_zone_dict]}  # add as many mappings as needed
    for k, v in lookup.items():
        if k in destination:
            temp_zone = self.determine_zone(value, v[1])
            data_type = v[0] + str(temp_zone)
            self.log_handler.update(destination + " " + data_type+"\n")
            break
```

This, however, might give you more versatility and might look tidier if you have a lot of conditions to add, but it won't vastly improve the performance. I don't think your performance bottleneck is here, anyway.

Comment: I was trying to figure out if you could construct some f-strings to include in the dictionary.

Comment: You can, but since the _zone_ dictionary differs from case to case, you'll have to keep a map anyway and in that case you might as well keep the `data_type` _prefix_ as well.